# Вылет из цикла при объявлении нового значения элементу массива

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

```
  for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        max=b[i][0];
        min=b[i][0];
        for (j=1;j<m;j++){
            if (min>b[i][j]){
                min=b[i][j];
                admin=j;
            }
            if (max<b[i][j]){
                max=b[i][j];
                admax=j;
            }
        }
        printf ("\nВ %d строке максимальный элемент равен %.2f, минимальный %.2f", i, max, min);
    }
```

Задание - найти максимальное и минимальное значение и поменять их местами
Весь цикл работает и код нормально работает, но если внутри `for(i=0;i<nn;i++){...}`
после `printf` добавить

```
b[i][admax]=min;
b[i][admin]=max;
```

То как только доходит до этой строки - заканчивается работа цикла и программы в общем

```
В 0 строке максимальный элемент равен 4,00, минимальный 1,00
```

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть на весь код и данные. 

Пока что - а если у вас нет, скажем, меньше первого или больше него - то чему у вас будет равен `admin` (соответственно, `admax`)? Я не вижу инициализации этих переменных, так что что там в них - неизвестно. Рекомендовал бы переписать `max=b[i][0];
        min=b[i][0];` как `max=b[i][admax=0];
        min=b[i][admin=0];`

Comment: Cпасибо, теперь работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменные **admin, admax** не иницилизированы никаким значением (мусором). Прога и вылетает. Нужно дописать условие, при каких случаях эти переменные имеют значение.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло